# Alternative for JComboBox without drop down list

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Java, Swing, JCombobox.

I need a single-line textbox with 2 arrows (up and down) instead of drop down list.

I'm sure that's pretty easy but i've not been succeeded to find solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vishal_aim I've tried to google. I just didn't know about JSpinner component. I thought that JComboBox can do this. So i've tried to extend combobox to change its view.

Comment: the online tutorial (referenced in the swing tag wiki) has a visual index of available components - just sayin' :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirement, `Java Swing` already has a component called `JSpinner`.

Answer (score 3):

have look at [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) with [`SpinnerListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#standard)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a 
`JList`. Just set the height of the list so that only one element is visible at a time. For further infomation please refer to this...

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/basicswingcomponentsII/